# JavaFX printing

Tags: javafx, javafx-2

Does JavaFX 2.0 supports printing? I have a text area from which I take the text and then  I want to print it, but it seems that there is not functionality for that.
Of course, here I am talking about printing to a printer. :)

Answer (score 11, accepted):

not yet supported. As a workaround you can make screenshot and print using Java2d.

See

[Copying the image of a ScatterChart to system clipboard in JavaFX 2.0](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8496977/copying-the-image-of-a-scatterchart-to-system-clipboard-in-javafx-2-0)

[Printing a BufferedImage in Java](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5283860/printing-a-bufferedimage-in-java)

**Update:**

JavaFX8 (which will be included into upcoming JDK8 release) has printing support. See nice example here: http://java.dzone.com/articles/introduction-example-javafx-8

Answer (score -1):

I believe it is already supported in JavaFX 2.2.

Comment: JavaFX printer API  was added in JavaFX 8, not in JavaFX 2.2