# Framework for Image, drawing and manipulation in Java?

Tags: java, image-processing, drawing, javafx-2

I want to create a small Java application that will be capable of simple image manipulation (layers etc) and drawing (simple shapes, fills, etc).

What framework is best to use for this? I was looking into JavaFX 2.0, it seemed that it was very appropiate for this but, it has no capabilities for exporting images (This is a must have functionality).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

JavaFX 2 will work for you.

Exporting images can be done through workaround described in [Copying the image of a ScatterChart to system clipboard in JavaFX 2.0](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8496977/copying-the-image-of-a-scatterchart-to-system-clipboard-in-javafx-2-0)

Comment: thanks a lot it works wonderfully, what about FX animations do you know a way to save them to gif for example

Comment: that's an interesing question :) Theoretically why not -- make a set of screenshots and use gif library to create an image out of them.